# How to set a hosting with php

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

Sorry for the question(not so specific), because i don't know how to ask it.
I want to create a platform with all includes like wix.com. IK BIG DREAMS. However, i don't know how they do to host every domain and every person that creates a website and does it thru php pages.

i mean, here a better example would be a hosting company, like they have php pages that automatically create your user, control panel and host you on a fragment of their servers after you pay and i want to do such a thing with like a dedicated server and host subdomains to my domain and those subdomains will be people's websites(just like wordpress.com does) and if they want to add a domain they just buy it and link the host to the domain.(WITH PHP, no server control panel or something like this)
PLS HELP

Answer (score 0):

It appears as your concern is to create cluster.Let us take an example of creating cluster having Database, Email Service, and Control Panel.
1]Create Database Server using mySql or ms-sql

2]Create Email server using Smarter mail

3]Create Server with Control Panel using Website Panel

4]Install Server component of Website Panel on Database Server and Smarter mail along with .net latest framework(version 4.5)

5]Generate virtual server using website panel feature which will allow to create user having facility of database, email service, FTP,DSNs etc.